# Renaming a published NPM module

Tags: npm

Is there any way to rename an NPM module that has already been published? I want to change the name of my module to more accurately match the API it exposes but would not like to leave people who have already installed it in the lurch.

Comment: Couldn't we also just publish a new major version with a post install script which replaces the package name in package.json and reruns install?

Answer (score 149, accepted):

There isn't any dedicated way to do that. A common technique is to use [npm-deprecate](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/commands/npm-deprecate) to give a warning that indicates the new package name.

```
npm deprecate my-project-name@"<= latest-version" "This project has been renamed. Install using new-project-name instead."
```

Example:

```
npm deprecate my-thing@"<= 0.2.3" "This project has been renamed. Install using my-new-thing instead."
```

[npm-deprecate documentation](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/commands/npm-deprecate)

Answer (score 29):

In simple words no you can't. But npm provides you a different solution called `npm deprecate`.

What it does is it marks a particular version or version ranges of that package as deprecated. So next if someone tries to install this package they get a warning package deprecated along with your custom message, in which you can easily specify your new package name.

Usage:

```
npm deprecate my-package-name@"< latest-version" "your message"
```

Your message can be any thing like:

```
WARNING: This project has been renamed to your-new-package-name. Install using new-package-name instead.
```

Comment: It's probably better to use `<=` rather than `<` so that it notifies for the latest version too?

Answer (score 20):

If the package was published less than 24 hours ago:

```
npm unpublish <wrong package name> --force
```

Comment: Yeah, this works if the package was just published (under 24 hours)

Answer (score 17):

From the documentation:

> Registry data is immutable, meaning once published, a package cannot
>   change. We do this for reasons of security and stability of the users
>   who depend on those packages.

However newly published packages - within **72 hours** - can be unpublished by running:

```
npm unpublish <package_name> -f
```

This will remove the package from the NPM registry if it was published less than **72 hours** ago. Then you can change your package's name and publish it again.

> Caution: You need to wait 24 hours if you try to republish package
>   with the same name

Answer (score 16):

Someone has built a handy little npm plugin for doing this easily

https://www.npmjs.com/package/@tiaanduplessis/pkg-rename

1. Install the package using `npm -g install @tiaanduplessis/pkg-rename`
2. Rename your npm module in the package.json file and save it
3. run `pkg-rename old-package-name`

From the documentation:

> This will get the latest version of the old package from npm and deprecate this and all previous published versions with a message:
>
> ```
> WARNING: This project has been renamed to new-package-name. Install using new-package-name instead.
> ```

You can also add the `--publish` flag to publish the new package name as part of the same action.

```
pkg-rename old-package-name --publish
```

Remember, rename the package in package.json **first**, *then* run the `pkg-rename` command.

Comment: npm should have a new slogan:

*saving javascript developers time as a service*

Comment: note that pkg-rename does not work if you have 2FA enabled with npm

Comment: Why install a third-party package in 3 steps when you can do the same thing in 3 steps using official tools?

Answer (score 3):

I once was in this situation. I published a package with the name `bowser-or-node` instead of `browser-or-node`.

There's no way to rename a package, you have to deprecate and publish a new package.

Although there's one other option. If you just published your package (less than 24 hours from time of publish) and if you're sure you're okay with deleting the package and publish a new one with the right name, you can go ahead and do it. But NPM won't allow you to delete the package once it's been 24 hours since the time of publish.

Fortunately I figured out that I published with the wrong name in less than 20 minutes. So I just deleted and published again with a new name.

Comment: Interesting, I'm trying to do that but I'm getting told "Package name too similar to existing packages" - even though I just deleted the old one.

Comment: Oh actually in my case, the similarity was to another package, not my old one.

Answer (score 0):

**Npm Unpublish policy**

Just to add that the solution suggested by a couple of other users:

```
npm unpublish your-package-name -f
// then you can re-publish with a new name
```

Does also work after 72 hours provided:

1. no other packages in the npm Public Registry depend on
2. had less than 300 downloads over the last week
3. has a single owner/maintainer

source: https://docs.npmjs.com/policies/unpublish

Apologies for posting this as an answer not a comment on one of these suggested solutions but I don't yet have the reputation points to comment.

Answer (score -3):

Something marvelous just happened to me: I managed to rename a package. It was originally known as stdout-renderer, but I changed every possible occurence of the name, and republished it after having deprecated the original and voila it shows up under its new name (cli-artist) undeprecated in the newly updated list. I'm not sure which field to change, but I would imagine it be in package.json because that's the only one where the casing matched in my case.

hope that helps!