# How to name Angular projects previously angular 2?

Tags: angularjs, angular

I have an open source project currently based on Angular 2. It has angular2 in it's name: [generator-angular2-firebase-bootstrap](https://www.npmjs.com/package/generator-angular2-firebase-bootstrap) (it's a yeoman generator). I am porting it to Angular 4 at the moment, but, before publishing it, I wonder how I should name it now:

1. Keep the name and indicate in the documentation that it's actually based on  Angular 4. At least, I will not loose the history associated with this project. Also, renaming is cumbersome in npm.
2. Change the name to generator-angular4-firebase-bootstrap but then at next iteration of Angular, I will have the same problem again.
3. Change the name to generator-angular-firebase-bootstrap.

In npm, changing the name means deprecating the current project and creating a new one. I would be very interested in knowing what are the options and what are the best practices from the community.

Comment: http://angularjs.blogspot.co.uk/2016/12/ok-let-me-explain-its-going-to-be.html

Comment: I know this blog post but I created my project the day b4 it was published.

Comment: I'd suggest `ng-` or `ngx-`.

Comment: I've edited the post to request for best practices (i.o opinions).

Answer (score 2):

I am facing the same problem with my open source projects. I will rename them from 
 `ng2-[...]` 
 to 
 `ngx-[..]` 
Seems like most of the community projects do that, e.g.:
  - https://github.com/swimlane/ngx-datatable 
  - https://github.com/scttcper/ngx-toastr 

Here is a SO on how to rename an npm module:
[Renaming a published NPM module](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28371669/renaming-a-published-npm-module)

 
I know renaming it is not an optimal solution, as you point out you will lose the history of the project.
But I think seen on a long term basis it's still the best way to go considering the Angular release schedule (2 major version releases per year): https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/docs/RELEASE_SCHEDULE.md#tentative-schedule-after-march-2017

Comment: It seems a good advice, thanks.