# renaming a npm module, minor change to the name => "package name too similar"

Tags: npm

I have a package named `prelude.ts`, but due to [some confusion](https://github.com/emmanueltouzery/prelude.ts/issues/20), I would like to rename it to `prelude-ts`. However I'm starting to wonder whether it's possible, because publishing under the new name fails with:

> Package name too similar to existing packages; try renaming your package to '@emmanueltouzery/prelude-ts' and publishing with 'npm publish --access=public' instead : prelude-ts

It's obviously conflicting with the old name.

What I would like to do is to publish the new package `prelude-ts` then [deprecate](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28841779/516188) the old package. I'm wondering, maybe if I first deprecate the existing package, I would be allowed to publish under the new name, but I currently have the feeling that it wouldn't work, and I don't dare to deprecate my current page to test this.

Must I come up with a completely different name, or is it possible to make a small naming change as I intended? Would it in fact work to deprecate my current package first, then publish under the new name?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So in the end the solution was to ask @npm_support by private message on twitter (they also mention on their website that you can contact them through the support@npmjs.com email).

They were extremely helpful (and extremely fast, in the PST timezone). They created a new project named `prelude-ts` even though I couldn't, using a security mechanism, then handed it to me.

I think it would not have been possible to solve this issue other than through npm support (short of picking a new, completely different, name for the library).